# TimeZone.IsAmbiguousTime, why does it fails for GMT ambiguous time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm in a situation where my server sends CEST time and I need to display it on UI as it's received from server, except the DST switch.The ambiguous hours in GMT should be converted to unambiguous hours in GMT.Maybe the below test can explain my intent.

```
[Test]
public void Should_process_server_time()
{
    var britishZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    var germanZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
    var firstAmbigiousMarchEntry = new DateTime(2011, 03, 27, 01, 00, 00);
    var secondAmbigiousMarchEntry = new DateTime(2011, 03, 27, 01, 30, 00);

    //Why does this fail even though 2011-03-27 01:00:00 is an ambigous time in GMT?
    Assert.That(britishZone.IsAmbiguousTime(firstAmbigiousMarchEntry));
    Assert.That(britishZone.IsAmbiguousTime(secondAmbigiousMarchEntry));

    var unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(firstAmbigiousMarchEntry, germanZone, britishZone);
    var unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(secondAmbigiousMarchEntry, germanZone, britishZone);

    Assert.That(britishZone.IsAmbiguousTime(unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry), Is.False);
    Assert.That(britishZone.IsAmbiguousTime(unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry), Is.False);

    Assert.That(unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry.Hour == 2);
    Assert.That(unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry.Minute == 0);
    Assert.That(unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry.Second == 0);

    Assert.That(unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry.Hour == 2);
    Assert.That(unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry.Minute == 30);
    Assert.That(unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry.Second == 0);

}
```

Please can you help? My intention is to convert the ambiguous time in british zone to unambiguous time in British zone, i.e 2011-03-27 01:00:00 to 2011-03-27 02:00:00.For this I need to determine whether the DateTime received is ambiguous in GMT zone, however the call fails.
My system is running with UK regional settings.

I tries with the below test, and it passes.Now I'm confused as what is the difference between `IsInvalidTime` and `IsAmbigoustime` when it comes to GMT zone?

```
[Test]
public void Should_process_server_time()
{
    var britishZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    var germanZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
    var firstAmbigiousMarchEntry = new DateTime(2011, 03, 27, 01, 00, 00);
    var secondAmbigiousMarchEntry = new DateTime(2011, 03, 27, 01, 30, 00);

    Assert.That(britishZone.IsInvalidTime(firstAmbigiousMarchEntry));
    Assert.That(britishZone.IsInvalidTime(secondAmbigiousMarchEntry));

    var unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(firstAmbigiousMarchEntry, germanZone, britishZone);
    var unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(secondAmbigiousMarchEntry, germanZone, britishZone);

    unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry = unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry.AddHours(2);
    unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry = unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry.AddHours(2);

    Assert.That(britishZone.IsAmbiguousTime(unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry), Is.False);
    Assert.That(britishZone.IsAmbiguousTime(unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry), Is.False);

    Assert.That(unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry.Hour == 2);
    Assert.That(unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry.Minute == 0);
    Assert.That(unAmbigiousFirstMarchEntry.Second == 0);

    Assert.That(unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry.Hour == 2);
    Assert.That(unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry.Minute == 30);
    Assert.That(unAmbigiousSecondMarchEntry.Second == 0);
}
```

Also do you think this could be implemented any better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is that GMT is never ambiguous. GMT is always +0. The time zone in London is called Western European Time, which is +0 in the winter and +1 in the summer.

Comment: Precisely. GMT is always GMT. It got no daylight saving time. For example: Swedish time is GMT+1 in the winter and GMT+2 in the summer.

Comment: <nitpick>WET is synonymous with GMT and is always UTC+0, the same as GMT. In the summer most of the countries using WET switch to WEST/BST, which is UTC+1.</nitpick> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_European_Time

Comment: If that is the case why does this test pass(please see the edit on my main question)? The question would be what is the difference between InvalidTime and AmbigousTime when it comes to GMT timezone?